# Force installing untrusted Safari extensions

Tags: safari, safari-extensions

Before Safari 9, I was able to install any extension on Safari without any problems, but after Apple updated its Developer Program, it seems that I can't install extensions not already signed by Apple and in Safari Extension Gallery. I had two untrusted extensions installed and working, but had to remove those and I can't install them again.

I'm still having hope, because when I double click the extension file, Safari shows me a dialog like this:

[image: Safari screen shot]

But nothing happens when I click on `Trust`. It just dismisses the dialog and won't install the extension. Is there any way I can install this extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after contacting one of the developers of an "untrusted" extension, they pointed out that this can be done normally in safe mode. You can boot your Mac in safe mode by holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> when booting.

Beware that your Mac performs really slow in safe mode, so download the extension you want to install before booting in safe mode.

[This](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/DistributingYourExtension/DistributingYourExtension.html) is the Apple Documentation page which points out there's no need for all extensions to be hosted on Safari Extensions Gallery.

Answer (score 18):

Copied from: [Safari 9 - I cannot install extensions](https://discussions.apple.com/message/29328892#29328892)

To install a *.safariextz* file, go to:

- System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Keyboard
    (for OS X 10.11.4+)

or

- System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Full Keyboard Access
    (for OS X 10.11.1 to 10.11.3)

Then at the bottom of that dialog box, change the *Full Keyboard Access:...* option from *Text boxes and lists only* to *All controls*. You can then dismiss that System Preferences window.

Then, return to installing the extension. Double click your Safari Extension file and when the *"Are you sure you want to install...*" dialog box appears, **do not** click on the *Trust* button. Instead, use <kbd>tab</kbd> to select the *Trust* button and then confirm by hitting <kbd>space</kbd>. That should install the extension as required.

Comment: I am on 10.11.4  and there is no  Full Keyboard Access in Shortcuts

Comment: On 10.11.4 it's now just called "Keyboard". The rest of the instruction is still fine. I'll update the answer itself. (But what a *bizarre* solution to the problem! Thanks Ruud!)

Comment: I've had to revert, for a second time, inappropriate cosmetic changes. Can we please just leave it as it is. My intention was to have the SysPref path instructions stand out, and to also make sure the OS X version dependency stood out. Also, I explicitly mention "mouse-click" to emphasize that *not* using the mouse is the essence of this workaround.

Comment: Why is it that way? I mean, that can't be an expected behavior.

Comment: @Nemo64 I wish I knew. Perhaps it's something that's broken with my profile, or installation. Haven't had a fresh install to test it though.

Comment: I have to say, I was sceptical about this, but it 100% worked for me. Insane!

Answer (score 3):

Try using the tab key to select "trust" and the space bar to click it. For whatever reason, this works for me.

Comment: At first, I assumed this answer was false, but I actually had the same issue and solved it by confirming the dialog using my keyboard. This requires keyboard accessibility settings to be reconfigured. See https://discussions.apple.com/message/29328892#29328892

Answer (score 3):

This problem also exists when using macOS Sierra 10.12 with a remote desktop client (like VNC). The solution is to install the extension directly on the physical machine.

Not sure about other version of OS X.